# File/Data transfer between two arbitrary sources

Tags: language-agnostic, sockets, transport

I'm looking for a simple way to implement this scenario:

Say I have two machines I'd like to share data between.  The location/addresses of these machines can change at any time.  I'd like both machines to check in to a central server to announce their availability.  One of the two systems wants to pull a file from the other.  I know that I can have the sink system make a request to the server, who then requests the file from the source, pulls it, then feeds it to the requester.  However, this seems inefficient from a bandwidth perspective.  The file will be transfered twice.  Is there a system in place where the source can broadcast it directly to the sink?

Without being able to guarantee things like port forwarding if a system is behind a firewall etc. I don't know of a way.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into P2P systems like BitTorrent? Seems somewhat  similar to me.

Comment: Looks like BitTorrent uses reverse connections.

Answer (score 2):

When machine `A` wants to send data to machine `B`, `A` sends a request to the central server `C`.  `C` asks `B` for permission.  If accepted, `C` gives `B`'s IP and port to `A`.  `A` attempts to connect to `B` directly.  If unsuccessful (ie, if `B` is behind a router/firewall), then `A` notifies `C` of the failure.  `C` then gives `A`'s IP and port to `B`.  `B` attempts to connect directly to `A` (which should be able to pass through `B`'s firewall/router).  If either connection is successful, then `A` has a direct connection to send data to `B`.  If both connections are unsuccessful (ie, if `A` is also behind a firewall/router), then `C` has to act as a proxy for all transfers between `A` and `B`.